Accessing tokens stored in localStorage from server-side
I'm attempting to implement a logout function that runs on the server-side. This function currently only removes tokens stored in localStorage upon login, as shown below:
const logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
  localStorage.removeItem('idToken');
};

However, this approach encounters an error since localStorage is inaccessible on the server-side.
Question:
How can I effectively remove the accessToken and idToken stored in localStorage from the server-side?
In the context of Nuxt 3 and removing tokens from localStorage on the server-side, I haven't directly tried modifying localStorage because it's not accessible there.
What I expected:
I expected the logout function to successfully remove the tokens (accessToken and idToken) from localStorage on the server after a successful logout, as it does on the client-side. This would effectively invalidate the user's session.

If I am not mistaken, localStorage is a client-only thing. There is hence no way to do such a thing IMO.

@kissu Should I change my way to store the tokens instead of using localStorage?

If you want to interact with both client and server side you will need to use something like cookies indeed. Not sure how you wish to manage your stuff but that's never a bad way to start. Otherwise you can put a short invalidation for your tokens so that they expire by themselves every 120s or alike. That way no need to do any hacks on the backend side of your Nuxt app.

Right now, I'm deleting the tokens on the client side once the server responds successfully. I think this is a good temporary solution, but eventually, I want to try integrating Nuxt Auth into my project.

There are quite a lot of auth utilities available for Nuxt so that you could use the official and clean way of doings things.

You should useCookie to do these things. By definition you won't have access to localStorage because that is local to client and not sent to server.
Example:
const accessToken = useCookie("accessToken");

accessToken.value = undefined; // this deletes cookie;

accessToken.value = "ezY.." // this sets the value of cookie;

This code will run both server-side and client-side.

Thanks, I was able to get the accessToken after using useCookie. Because previously I forced to use localStorage on the server side but I still didn't find the way
